# Setting up postfix for mass email for multi domain

Tags: postfix, email-server

I'm newbie here, I want to send mass email with diffrent email address which will not belong to same domain. for e.g. abc@example.com, pqr@domain.com ....
The objective of this to have an mass email compaign for clients.
  What are the chances that email providers will ban my ip or domain? and how I can avoid it.

Comment: If what you're doing is sending email that people have actually signed up for and want, then you should be using a mailing list manager (e.g. Mailman), or a reputable email list provider, that will make it easy for recipients to change their subscriptions. 

If the emails aren't solicited, then you *will* be banned, and rightly so.

Comment: @JennyD I want to built a system like mailchimp where my company client will add emaill address and then send emails to their users. The email list manager which we are building will have unsubscribe and  opt in functionality. We will never send any mail to user who has unsubscribed from clients campaign. 

I don't want to use existing opensource apps just because of the UI.  those are really bad and don't give nice templating feature.

Comment: @m4k run, don't walk, away from this project...

Comment: @gravyface I would run to achieve this project and try to make successful :)

Comment: @m4k The way to be successful with this is to either have a very good understanding of spam and email marketing before starting to build a solution, or otherwise to outsource it to someone who does. This isn't just a can of worms, it's a shipping container of Shai-Hulud.

Comment: @JennyD agreed, I'm here to understand the complexity. Without trying nothing can be achieved.

Comment: The thing is that most of the complexity is social rather than technical. That makes it a lot harder to give concise and accurate responses. But one thing that I don't think has been mentioned - in addition to having the proper subscribe/unsubscribe mechanisms, it is essential to have an actual human being handle spam and abuse complaints, and to respond promptly. The way you handle those complaints will make a lot of difference to your company's reputation.

Comment: Could you please provide your outgoing IPs that I can block them right away? Mass mailers who don't thoroughly understand the implications of sending thousands of emails that way are not worth a first try.

Answer (score 3):

If the emails are actually solicited, i.e. the recipients have agreed to them in advance, then most providers won't block you. Some still may, if the program you're using to send the emails is adversely affecting their systems.

I'd really strongly advise you to read up on spam before starting on this. If you can't be certain of how to do this right, don't do it yourself. There are companies out there that are doing this professionally and doing it right, without getting anybody blocked.

I'd start by looking at [the Marketing FAQ at Spamhaus](http://www.spamhaus.org/faq/section/Marketing%20FAQs). It gives you some information of the right way to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your advice I'm seriously looking into it, and after your words I'm getting more challenged to take this project.

How much postfix can help me apart from just sending email, does postfix also can authenticate email address and add SPF/DKIM authentication?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "authenticate email address" here. Postfix has support for SPF and DKIM - there's info at http://www.postfix.org/features.html .

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest you if you really want to build system like mail chimp,constant contact etc 
then first of all you need to understand their system how it works,what protocols they use to determine spamers ,how feed back loop works, and how they monitor their whole network.

After that you need to know how to configure your network and servers to achive this kind of services and how you will authenticate your clients  mails using DKIM,SPF.

You should also implement rules on your clients that they should not use purchased mailling lists/database.

Comment: I'm trying to understand, how all this works, but until I really jump into it I wont be able to understand. 
Do you have any idea how one can authenticate email address with DKIM,SPF of clients?